# Move window TITLE (NOT BUTTONS) to left a-la-windows in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: gnome, 20.04, window, settings, titlebar

I have my Ubuntu setup as close to Windows as possible (more comfortable to me.) How do I move JUST THE WINDOW TITLE/LABEL to the left hand side like you would find in Windows?

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I...keep. finding. posts. about. the. buttons.... I'm okay with the buttons on the right. It's the window Label I want on the left.

Thnx!

Comment: That is determined by the theme. Just changing the location of the title would require editing the code of the stylesheet.